Using count with completions
Say I'm using the completion menu in vim, and I see the word I need as the 9th suggestion. Is there a way to use a count and execute <C-n> 9 times to access the desired completion?

Printable characters, including numbers, are inserted as you type them so there is no built-in way to do exactly what you want in an idiomatic way, like 9<C-n>.
